# How should i read JSON with enumbered Object?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to read that JSON using Jackson in Java:

```
{
  "node1":
  {
    "id": "123",
    "categories":
    {
      "category1":
      {
        ...
      },
      "category2":
      {
        ...
      }
      <next category>
    }
  },

  "node2":
  {
    "id": "456",
    "categories":
    {
      "category1":
      {
        ...
      },
      <next category>
    }
  }

  <next node>
  ...
}
```

How to read that JSON? 
Should I use List or Map? 
What should my Java objects look like?

When I'm trying to read that JSON to object that contains `List<Node> node` it throws exception: 
Unrecognized field "node1"

Comment: You should contact provided of that JSON and ask him to get rid of `nodeX` keys and use array JSON array, so instead of `{key1:{}, key2:{}}` it would become `[{...}, {...}]`.

Comment: You should probably check their [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) before posting in here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `List<Node>`use

```
{ [ "node1": {}, "node2": {}... ] ...}
```

The same thing for categories:

```
[ {"category1": {...}}, {"category2": {...}} ]
```

Have a look [JSON Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp).
Current json maps to following POJO because you use json Objects instead Arrays :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class NodeContainer {

    @JsonProperty("node1")
    private Node node;
    @JsonProperty("node2")
    private Node node2;

    @JsonProperty("node1")
    public Node getNode() {
        return node;
    }

    @JsonProperty("node1")
    public void setNode(Node node) {
        this.node = node;
    }

    @JsonProperty("node2")
    public Node getNode2() {
        return node2;
    }

    @JsonProperty("node2")
    public void setNode2(Node node2) {
        this.node2 = node2;
    }
}
```